# OpenSSH for Windows ignoring Match User directives

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, openssh, sftp

I am using`OpenSSH` for `Windows 7.7p1` on `Windows 1903`. I used `Match User xxxx` in `sshd_config` file, in `Program Data -> SSH` to change xxxx's root directory to another path in the `filesystem`, apart from a few other directives.

This method used to work fine with an earlier version, I could connect using this user and come to the changed root directory.

With the new stable version, this `Match User` directive seemingly isn't respected.

Looking at the `sshd` logs, I see this...

```
26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug1: userauth-request for user TestLocalAccount service ssh-connection method none [preauth]

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: mm_request_receive entering

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 297

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: checking match for 'User TestLocalAccount' user testlocalaccount host 127.0.0.1 addr 127.0.0.1 laddr 127.0.0.1 lport 22

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: match not found

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1

26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
```

These logs -

```
26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 297
26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: checking match for 'User TestLocalAccount' user testlocalaccount host 127.0.0.1 addr 127.0.0.1 laddr 127.0.0.1 lport 22
26948 2019-09-30 15:10:29.745 debug3: match not found
```

- do not appear when there is no `Match User` directive in `sshd_config`. At least that and the fact that it considers a config file change seems to indicate this is the correct file (Prog Files -> OpenSSH has another sshd_config_default).

The relevant section in the sshd_config looks like -

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

Match User TestLocalAccount
    ChrootDirectory C:\Users\TestLocalAccount\Downloads
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
```

None of the directives within the `Match user` section are respected. Opening a session with `TestLocalAccount` just opens up the home user profile of the same.
I am trying this with `SecureFX` SFTP client.

Comment: Have you filed/reviewed [bug reports](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues) on Microsoft's Win32-OpenSSH's GitHub?

Comment: I had a glance and searched that page, checked release notes for the latest version, for this, but didn't find anything close to the issue I've been having. I rather think if this were broken, it'd be a fairly big thing.

Comment: I would file a bug report then, which should garner some input from others who can troubleshoot.  The developers working on Win32-OpenSSH generally reply when issues are filed, and other GitHub users frequently check the issues page to offer help to others.  Win32-OpenSSH isn't as widespread as OpenSSH is, so it's entirely possible either others aren't utilizing it with `Match User` or others haven't upgraded to 7.7x and therefore aren't aware the update has broken something.

Comment: After some checking,  turns out the `Match User` value,  i.e., username, should be in lower caps. Perhaps this is widely known (or borrowed from Linix environment), but strange one for me.Anyway, once username is in lower caps, seems to work for me.

Comment: What does it means lower caps?